# Command to highlight the element which is being executed

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium IDE, we can highlight element (which is highlighted by yellow colour). I mean in command text field we enter command like - verifyElementPresent, in Target field we enter something like - id=nav-unanswered & when we click on 'Find' button that element on webpage is highlighted. Is there any way in Selenium-webdriver with Ruby, we can highlight every element which is begin executed as script runs?

Answer (score 0):

There is a java script code, which you can call in the program to highlight an element. but it can be used only with Selenium-RC or WebDriverBackedSelenium.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/trunk/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/internal/seleniumemulation/htmlutils.js

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this in selenium+java

```
public void highlightElement(WebElement element) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) this.getDriver();
            js.executeScript(
                    "arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
                    element, "color: yellow; border: 3px solid yellow;");
            js.executeScript(
                    "arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);",
                    element, "");

        }

    }
```